# Can not find `eosio/eosio.hpp` while compiling with eosio-cpp

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-cpp

I used the documentation provided by [EOSI](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract). I made all the required installation as suggested in the docs. While writing the hello world contract, I face this issue when running the following command `eosio-cpp -abigen -o hello.wasm hello.cpp`. Please help. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Machine (As I saw in some posts that this error is machine specific)

```
hello.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'eosio/eosio.hpp' file not found
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Depending on the version of the cdt you use you may have to use #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the eosio.cdt version

1.5.x version using the `eosiolib/eosio.hpp`

1.6.x version using the `eosio/eosio.hpp`

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, just copy the contract files to the folder where eosio-cpp is located (in my case it is in /home/vgagaleski/eosio.cdt/build/bin, navigate to the folder and execute the command. You will see the wasm file in the same folder.
p.s change vgagaleski with your username

Answer (score 0):

the version of cdt used required `#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>` instead of  `#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>`.